# Webpack loader not getting all imported files

Tags: webpack, tslint

I'm trying to get tslint-loader to TS-lint all my files, but it seems that it's getting only the "entry" file.

I think i did everything exactly as they say, but I'm only getting one file linted: the main. It's like Webpack can't recognize the imports inside that file

Webpack config:

```
{
  "tslint": {
    "failOnHint": true
  },
  "entry": {
    "main": ".\/src\/mainBootstrapper.ts"
  },
  "output": {
    "path": ".\/dist",
    "libraryTarget": "commonjs2",
    "filename": "[name].0.0.0-dev.js"
  },
  "resolve": {
    "extensions": [
      "",
      ".ts",
      ".tsx"
    ]
  },
  "module": {
    preLoaders: [
      { test: /(\.tsx?)$/,
        loader: 'tslint-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
    loaders: [ { test: /(\.tsx?)$/, loader: 'awesome-ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ } ]
  }
}
```

And my main.ts:

```
import {Bootstrapper} from 'core-lib';
import MainModule from './main/mainModule';

new Bootstrapper(new MainModule ()).start();
```

In this case, only main.ts gets linted, core-lib shouldn't get linted and it doesn't (because it's inside node_modules), and mainModule should get linted but it doesn't. mainModule is a .tsx file, because it's a React app.... Maybe this is why it fails?

Or is there any way to tell webpack to load all files inside a subfolder?

Comment: I had same problem, the problem was .js files created by visual studio. Webpack was loading those .js files while resolving dependencies and not the .ts files. To fix the problem i modified sequence of extensions in resolve settings in webpack config. like extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']